# How to get selected artboard index from AI image?

Tags: vector, adobe, ghostscript, adobe-illustrator

GhostScript can render AI images where each artboard is represented as a page. So I can tell to GS what page (ie artboard) I want to render.
But how to determine what artboard is selected in AI image programmatically?

[Download a sample AI image with 2 artboards (ArtBoard2 is selected)](http://daminion.net/files/ArtBoardSample.ai)

Comment: As KenS mentions, I don't think GS know about AI artboards and therefore won't handle them. You can script Illustrator with Javascript however and find out which is the active artboard: ```#target illustrator

var doc = app.activeDocument;
$.writeln(doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex());
$.writeln(doc.artboards[doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex()]);```. You can then use that data to export an image/pdf/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript only renders .ai files when the file contains valid PostScript (or PDF in later versions). Not all .ai files can be rendered.

Without knowing what an 'artboard' is represented as (though your question seems to indicate it is a page) in a PostScript program or PDF file its not possible to answer your question, perhaps you could post an example that might make things clearer.

However I very strongly suspect the answer is 'you can't'.

Comment: Ken, thanks for your response! I've attached a sample AI file to my post with 2 artboards. I selected the second ArtBoard2 in Illustrator and saved the file.

Comment: Well the file is a valid PDF file (change the extension to .pdf and Acrobat will open it) and it contains two pages, one with a green square and the other with a red circle. The Illustrator code is saved as specifically named objects in the PDF, which is why its so large. The PDF file does have layers and if I turn them off I get blank pages. What was it you wanted from Ghostscript ?